# iOS SIGSEGV Crash on SIGNAL (CFSetRemoveValue)

Tags: objective-c, crash, segmentation-fault, bugsense

Here is the Stacktrace from BugSense,
I'm using XCode 5 with ARC.
I got this crash this when I using a UIWebView.
Does anyone know what is the problem of it? Thank you!

```
0 CoreFoundation 0x2f8c6302 CFSetRemoveValue + 5
1 CFNetwork 0x2f5c16f1 + 24
2 CoreFoundation 0x2f947037 + 30
3 CoreFoundation 0x2f8bf8df CFRelease + 462
4 WebCore 0x37d5d3f3 + 142
5 WebCore 0x37d5d2e3 + 34
6 WebCore 0x37d5d2ad + 40
7 WebCore 0x37c8500b + 210
8 WebCore 0x37c8514f + 10
9 WebCore 0x37c18757 + 110
10 WebCore 0x37c18383 + 626
11 WebCore 0x37cceaab + 482
12 WebCore 0x37baefb3 + 98
13 WebCore 0x37c788d9 + 364
14 WebCore 0x37c78757 + 134
15 WebCore 0x37c77eb3 + 322
16 WebCore 0x37c77b43 + 1210
17 WebCore 0x37c7745d + 460
18 WebCore 0x37bf0b43 + 266
19 WebCore 0x37bf09db + 250
20 WebCore 0x37bee733 + 1562
21 WebCore 0x38306db9 + 464
22 WebCore 0x37bee0d3 + 882
23 WebCore 0x37bf08bd + 100
24 WebCore 0x37bee77d + 1636
25 WebCore 0x37bedfc1 + 608
26 WebCore 0x37bf08bd + 100
27 WebCore 0x37bee77d + 1636
28 WebCore 0x37bedfc1 + 608
29 WebCore 0x37bedcdf + 102
30 WebCore 0x37bed73f + 514
31 WebKit 0x3859d423 + 354
32 WebKit 0x3859d251 + 136
33 WebKit 0x3859d17d + 36
34 WebCore 0x37bed09f + 274
35 WebCore 0x37bed1d3 + 582
36 WebCore 0x37bed1d3 + 582
37 WebCore 0x37bed1d3 + 582
38 WebCore 0x37bed1d3 + 582
39 WebCore 0x37becf4b + 58
40 WebCore 0x37becf0b + 54
41 WebCore 0x37bece4f + 662
42 WebCore 0x37bec835 + 504
43 QuartzCore 0x31e40f91 + 2192
44 QuartzCore 0x31f1bd6d + 52
45 QuartzCore 0x31e406f3 + 82
46 QuartzCore 0x31e4039b + 1106
47 QuartzCore 0x31e2403d + 208
48 QuartzCore 0x31e23cd5 + 24
49 QuartzCore 0x31e236df + 230
50 QuartzCore 0x31e234ef + 314
51 QuartzCore 0x31e1d21d + 56
52 CoreFoundation 0x2f95a2a5 + 20
53 CoreFoundation 0x2f957c49 + 284
54 CoreFoundation 0x2f8c2f31 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 556
55 CoreFoundation 0x2f8c2cf3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
56 WebCore 0x37bad11b + 418
57 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3a833919 + 140
58 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3a83388b _pthread_start + 102
59 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x3a831aa4 thread_start + 8
```

This crash report is from SIGNAL -> CFSetRemoveValue
Running on iOS7 iPhone4

Comment: Can you please post the code snippet you are using ?

Comment: Every time it crash on the different run time. Therefore i even can't know where should I start to debug. The crash is not fixed.

Answer (score 1):

i'm having the same crash. However i've managed to symbolicate it so it'll contain more useful information. If it helps, at first I thought the device was running out of memory and crashing, however after carefully profiling a device whilst it crashed, I notice plenty is available. So this can't be the case. The website loaded in the UIWebView was an intensive HTML5 Game.

```
Thread : Crashed: WebThread (com.apple.root.default-overcommit-priority)
0  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001872491c4 CFSetRemoveValue + 36
1  CFNetwork                      0x0000000186ee2b3c __CFURLCache::removeMMappedDataFromSet(void*) + 60
2  CFNetwork                      0x0000000186ee2b3c __CFURLCache::removeMMappedDataFromSet(void*) + 60
3  CFNetwork                      0x0000000186ee49c8 mmapFileDeallocate(void*, void*) + 40
4  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001872ee81c __CFDataDeallocate + 44
5  CoreFoundation                 0x000000018724213c CFRelease + 316
6  WebCore                        0x0000000190d99ef4 WebCore::SharedBuffer::clear() + 212
7  WebCore                        0x0000000190d99d68 WebCore::SharedBuffer::~SharedBuffer() +    56
8  WebCore                        0x0000000190d99d14 WebCore::ResourceBuffer::~ResourceBuffer() + 68
9  WebCore                        0x0000000190c79e90      WebCore::CachedResource::~CachedResource() + 300
10 WebCore                        0x0000000190c79d54 WebCore::CachedCSSStyleSheet::~CachedCSSStyleSheet() + 172
11 WebCore                        0x0000000190c79c98 WebCore::CachedCSSStyleSheet::~CachedCSSStyleSheet() + 20
12 WebCore                        0x0000000190bec558 WebCore::CachedResource::deleteIfPossible() + 160
13 WebCore                        0x0000000190cdd660 WebCore::MemoryCache::pruneDeadResourcesToSize(unsigned int) + 588
14 WebCore                        0x0000000190b661c4 WebCore::MemoryCache::prune() + 132
15 WebCore                        0x0000000190c6b4f4 WebCore::BitmapImage::draw(WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::FloatRect const&, WebCore::FloatRect const&, WebCore::ColorSpace, WebCore::CompositeOperator, WebCore::BlendMode, WebCore::RespectImageOrientationEnum) + 504
16 WebCore                        0x0000000190cc9ac4 WebCore::Image::drawTiled(WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::FloatRect const&, WebCore::FloatPoint const&, WebCore::FloatSize const&, WebCore::ColorSpace, WebCore::CompositeOperator, WebCore::BlendMode) + 568
17 WebCore                        0x0000000190cc986c WebCore::GraphicsContext::drawTiledImage(WebCore::Image*, WebCore::ColorSpace, WebCore::IntRect const&, WebCore::IntPoint const&, WebCore::IntSize const&, WebCore::CompositeOperator, bool, WebCore::BlendMode) + 288
18 WebCore                        0x0000000190bbb0cc WebCore::RenderBoxModelObject::paintFillLayerExtended(WebCore::PaintInfo const&, WebCore::Color const&, WebCore::FillLayer const*, WebCore::LayoutRect const&, WebCore::BackgroundBleedAvoidance, WebCore::InlineFlowBox*, WebCore::LayoutSize const&, WebCore::CompositeOperator, WebCore::RenderObject*) + 4064
19 WebCore                        0x0000000190bb9ef4 WebCore::RenderBox::paintFillLayers(WebCore::PaintInfo const&, WebCore::Color const&, WebCore::FillLayer const*, WebCore::LayoutRect const&, WebCore::BackgroundBleedAvoidance, WebCore::CompositeOperator, WebCore::RenderObject*) + 624
20 WebCore                        0x0000000190bb9bcc WebCore::RenderBox::paintBackground(WebCore::PaintInfo const&, WebCore::LayoutRect const&, WebCore::BackgroundBleedAvoidance) + 476
21 WebCore                        0x0000000190bb8b94 WebCore::RenderBox::paintBoxDecorations(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::LayoutPoint const&) + 464
22 WebCore                        0x0000000190bb61ac WebCore::RenderBlock::paintObject(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::LayoutPoint const&) + 108
23 WebCore                        0x0000000190bb87b0 WebCore::RenderBlock::paint(WebCore::PaintInfo&, WebCore::LayoutPoint const&) + 292
24 WebCore                        0x0000000190bb5e80 WebCore::RenderLayer::paintBackgroundForFragments(WTF::Vector<WebCore::LayerFragment, 1ul, WTF::CrashOnOverflow> const&, WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::LayoutRect const&, bool, WebCore::RenderLayer::LayerPaintingInfo const&, unsigned int, WebCore::RenderObject*) + 348
25 WebCore                        0x0000000190bb3d40 WebCore::RenderLayer::paintLayerContents(WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::RenderLayer::LayerPaintingInfo const&, unsigned int) + 1404
26 WebCore                        0x0000000190d2124c WebCore::RenderLayerBacking::paintIntoLayer(WebCore::GraphicsLayer const*, WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::IntRect const&, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 316
27 WebCore                        0x0000000190d20f7c WebCore::RenderLayerBacking::paintContents(WebCore::GraphicsLayer const*, WebCore::GraphicsContext&, unsigned int, WebCore::IntRect const&) + 356
28 WebCore                        0x0000000190d20e00 WebCore::GraphicsLayer::paintGraphicsLayerContents(WebCore::GraphicsContext&, WebCore::IntRect const&) + 156
29 WebCore                        0x000000019102de14 non-virtual thunk to WebCore::GraphicsLayerCA::platformCALayerPaintContents(WebCore::GraphicsContext&, WebCore::IntRect const&) + 32
30 WebCore                        0x0000000190d20a14 drawLayerContents(CGContext*, CALayer*, WebCore::PlatformCALayer*) + 776
31 QuartzCore                     0x0000000189f176c0 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 2792
32 QuartzCore                     0x0000000189f16bc8 x_blame_allocations + 112
33 QuartzCore                     0x0000000189f16758 CA::Layer::display_() + 1260
34 WebCore                        0x0000000190d20684 -[WebLayer display] + 68
35 QuartzCore                     0x0000000189ef701c CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 244
36 QuartzCore                     0x0000000189ef6ce4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 44
37 QuartzCore                     0x0000000189ef6560 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 280
38 QuartzCore                     0x0000000189ef6304 CA::Transaction::commit() + 424
39 QuartzCore                     0x0000000189eefc38 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
40 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000187307858 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
41 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000187304ae0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
42 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000187245df8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 492
43 WebCore                        0x0000000190b633bc RunWebThread(void*) + 472
44 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000193fbfe1c _pthread_body + 168
45 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x0000000193fbfd74 _pthread_body
```